# How to get http headers information of request in soapUI?

Tags: java, soap, soapui

I am consuming a soap service using Java 1.8. Here is relevant code which create the message and call the service:

```
String URLString = "https://endpoint url";
URL url =  new URL(URLString);


SOAPConnectionFactory factory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConn = factory.createConnection();
                       
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(createString.getBytes());
SOAPMessage request= MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
                       
MimeHeaders headers = request.getMimeHeaders();
headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "Create");
                       
request.saveChanges();                    
SOAPMessage response = soapConn.call(request, url);
....
```

The server respond with 500:server error, so I copy the string  that I used to create the SOAPMessage object to soapUI. soapUI was able to successfully connect to the server and perform the create action.

Does my code contains any error? Also how can I the get details of the http headers that send out from soapUI?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SoapUI, you can see the 'raw request' for a request step in a test.

Once you make an API call from SoapUI and have get a response, you should be able to see the 'Raw' tab.  This shows exactly what SoapUI sent to the web service, including the headers.

Note, I've just checked this in SoapUI 5.6.0 (free version).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to get the headers to continue my trouble shooting.

Answer (score 0):

It turn out that I need to add encoding option when I get the byte array from "createString".